# How to connect optocoupler module to ABL sensor and Ender 3 board

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, z-probe

I am trying to figure out how to wire up Auto Bed Leveling (ABL) on my Ender 3 using the optocoupler and inductive proximity sensor below.

I cannot figure out how to wire it all together, all the tutorials I have found are for 2 and 3 wire per side of the optocoupler.

[image: NOYITO Optocoupler Isolation MOS FET 10A DC 2.7-27V High-Power Field Effect Tube Driver Module 0-20Khz PWM Switch Control Board Development Board Module]

[image: uxcell 4mm Inductive Proximity Approach Sensor Switch Detector NPN NO DC 6-36V 300mA 3-Wire LJ12A3-4-Z/BX]

Comment: VERY related: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6358/inductive-sensor-in-24-v-machine

Answer (score 2):

Connecting is pretty straightforward like the other modules, difference is an extra input lead.

From e.g. [here](https://www.desertcart.ae/products/92694483-noyito-optocoupler-isolation-mos-fet-10-a-dc-2-7-27-v-high-power-field-effect-tube-driver-module-0-20-khz-pwm-switch-control-board-development-board-module): Module interface description:

1. DC+: Positive DC power supply.
2. DC- : Negative DC power supply.
3. PWM: Signal input (connect MCU port, PLC interface, DC power supply, etc.)
4. GND: The negative terminal of the signal
5. OUT+: Positive output terminal (connected to the device positive)
6. OUT-: Negative output terminal (connected to device negative)

So, 1 and 2 connect to your power supply that matches the voltage of the logic of your microprocessor (5 V) as this must be linked to 5 and 6 which are connected to the endstop signal and ground respectively.

As for the sensor, blue is GND, black is signal (PWM) and brown is power as seen in e.g. [this answer](/a/6359).

Comment: Blue is GND?! Well I never. Completely contrary to convention. Utter madness! LOL... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an *addendum* to 0scar's answer, as I didn't want to edit it in to his post.

For completion, the sensor's internal schematic is on the side of the sensor itself<sup>1</sup>:

[image: Sensor schematic]

where:

- PNP - 1 BN - Brown - V<sub>SUPPLY</sub>
- N/O - 4 BK - Black - Sensor output
- 4 mm - 3 BU - Blue  - GND

However, the complete diagram, taken from [Instructables - Enable Auto Leveling for Your 3D Printer With an Inductive Sensor (Marlin Firmware)](https://www.instructables.com/id/Enable-Auto-Leveling-for-your-3D-Printer-Marlin-Fi/), can be seen here:

[image: Complete schematic]

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Taken from [this image](https://www.picclickimg.com/d/w1600/pict/273297496840_/4mm-Inductive-Proximity-Approach-Sensor-Switch-PNP-NO.jpg), which was on this product page, [4mm Inductive Proximity Approach Sensor Switch PNP NO DC 6-36V 200mA Cylinder](https://picclick.com/4mm-Inductive-Proximity-Approach-Sensor-Switch-PNP-NO-273297496840.html):

[image: Sensor image#1]

There is a bit more to the schematic, which can be glimpsed here (on the left hand side):

[image: Sensor image#2]

A fuller, but blurry, view of the left hand side can be seen [here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41kMRIsIl4L.jpg), from this [product page](https://weshop.co.id/amazon/item/uxcell-4mm-inductive-proximity-approach-sensor-switch-pnp-nc-dc-6-36v-200ma-3-wire-lj12a3-4-zay-cylinder-class-B07CWRHG4S.html):

[image: Left hand side of sticker on sensor]